# EF code first and Paging

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

we are using EF 6.1 and code first along with the Unit of work and repository pattern.

the confusion we are facing is that at many places its written that if we use `Skip` & `Take` on a Dbset, the paging is automatically handled.
but when we see the query being created,  it does not contain any clause for paging.

kindly assist what is the possible case , the sample code is as follows:

```
 public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetSorted(Func<TEntity, Object> order,int skip, int take, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;



            foreach (var include in includes)
            {
                query = dbSet.Include(include);
            }

            IEnumerable<TEntity> data = dbSet.OrderBy(order).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();

            //IEnumerable<TEntity> data = query.OrderBy(order).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();

            return data;
        }
```

any help appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `order` parameter needs to be of `Expression<Func<TEntity, TSortBy>>` type in order to match the signature of `Queryable.OrderBy()`. When you're passing a delegate (`Func<TEntity, Object>`), the only `OrderBy()` overload that will match this argument is `Enumerable.OrderBy()` and not the `Queryable.OrderBy()` that you're expecting (both are extension-methods of course).

When the sorting is being done by `Enumerable.OrderBy()` (Linq-to-Objects), the query must be executed first (since Linq-to-Objects is meant for working with objects that are already in memory).

However, when `Queryable.OrderBy()` is invoked, the order-by expression is being passed to the Linq provider that is then capable of parsing and translating it to a store query (SQL in this case).

So, when you're passing `Func<TEntity, Object>` to `OrderBy`, you're getting `IEnumerable<TEntity>` in return, and further (chained) calls to `Skip()` and `Take()` are no longer intercepted by Linq-To-Entities.

This is how your method signature should look like:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetSorted<TSortedBy>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TSortedBy>> order, int skip, int take, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534863(v=vs.100).aspx)